# Make array of String as Key Value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting a raw data like this

```
SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017;
```

I want to make this as a key value pair. So, first I separated the data by `;` like this

```
data.split(';');
```

**Output**

```
[ 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld',
  'SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld',
  'SERVER_PORT=3000',
  'SERVER_WS_PORT=4000',
  'NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/',
  'MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb',
  'MONGODB_HOST=localhost',
  'MONGODB_PORT=27017'
]
```

Now I want to make it as key value pair

**Expected Output**

```
[ 'SECRET_TOKEN'='Iwillruletheworld',
  'SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN'='Iwillruletheworld',
  'SERVER_PORT'='3000',
  'SERVER_WS_PORT'='4000',
  'NODE_URI'='http://test.abc.com/#/',
  'MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI'='mongodb',
  'MONGODB_HOST'='localhost',
  'MONGODB_PORT'='27017'
]
```

I want to insert `'` wherever `=` occurs. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Expected output is an invalid javascript output format. Perhaps you wanted a **key value pair object**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want an **object** as a result instead (since the output you provided is actually invalid), you could split by `;`, remove empty items (`.filter(Boolean)`) and `reduce` to build up a key-value pair object.

Of course, this example assumes there are no duplicate keys in the input.

```js
let input = `SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017;`;

let res = input.split(';').filter(Boolean).reduce((acc, next) => {
  let [key, value] = next.split('=');
  acc[key] = value;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Edit (2021): another more "modern" solution could also be using `Object.fromEntries` instead of `.reduce`. The result is exactly the same, it's just another similar approach.

```js
let input = `SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017;`;

const mapEntries = Object.fromEntries(
  input.split(';').filter(Boolean).map(v => v.split('='))
);
console.log(mapEntries);
```

Comment: It was helpful but my raw data doesn't have any `'`

Comment: @Chris that's irrelevant, it's just a string declaration ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can turn it to a JavaScript object (not an array):

```js
var arr = [ 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld',
  'SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld',
  'SERVER_PORT=3000',
  'SERVER_WS_PORT=4000',
  'NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/',
  'MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb',
  'MONGODB_HOST=localhost',
  'MONGODB_PORT=27017'
];

var obj = {};

arr.forEach((x) => {
  var kv = x.split('=');
  obj[kv[0]] = kv[1];
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split with `;` then split each with `=` and return array of object using `Array.prototype.map` then use `Object.assign` to convert it into `object`

```js
let str = 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017';
let out = Object.assign(str.split(';').map(e => ({[e.split('=')[0]]:e.split('=')[1]})));
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to have an array of strings:

```
const str = 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017;'
const strArray = str.split(';');
const corrArray = strArray.map(s=> s.replace('=', "'='")).map(s=> `'${s}'`);
console.log(corrArray);
```

If you want objects:

```
const str = 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017;'
const objs = str.split(';').map(a=> {
    const divided = a.split('=');
    const obj = {};
    obj[divided[0]] = divided[1];
    return obj;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = 'SECRET_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SECRET_REFRESH_TOKEN=Iwillruletheworld;SERVER_PORT=3000;SERVER_WS_PORT=4000;NODE_URI=http://test.abc.com/#/;MONGODB_DEFAULT_URI=mongodb;MONGODB_HOST=localhost;MONGODB_PORT=27017';
//assuming the data you receive is a string

let arr = data.split(';');
let dataObj = {};
for (let piece of arr){
   let pieceToKeyVal = piece.split('=');
   dataObj[pieceToKeyVal[0]] = pieceToKeyVal[1];
}
console.log(dataObj);
```